# How to use hydra compose API to read yaml from a nested directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, fb-hydra

I am trying to print the `src.yaml` from a nested directory below

```
Main_dir:
 conf:
  project:
    test_project1:
      env:
        source:
            src.yaml
```

src.yaml

```
table: TEST_TABLE
DB:Test_DB
```

I tried the following hydra API

```
with initialize(version_base=None, config_path="../../conf"):
 cfg = compose(config_name="config", overrides = ["project=test_project1","+source=src"])
 print(cfg)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
hydra.errors.ConfigCompositionException: Could not override 'project'. No match in the default list
```

How can I get rid to of this error?

Comment: your `src.yaml` is invalid. Either you have to indent the continuation line of the unquoted scalar "TEST_TABLE DB:Test_DB" or you need to make it two key-value pairs in the root level mapping by inserting a space after the colon to make it a value indicator

Comment: Hi @Anthon..  Thanks for your replay..  In actual scenario the application reads yaml directly and there is no error as you mentioned.. This is the dummy yaml.. 
The issue now i am facing here is traversing through the directory to read the yaml and i am not sure how to override that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`project=test_project1` means that there is a CONFIG named test_project1. Not a directory.

The Compose API gives you the same config composition capabilities `@hydra.main()` gives you. What you are trying to do is not supported in that form.

Something like this is more likely to work:

```py
with initialize(version_base=None, config_path="../../conf"):
 cfg = compose(config_name="config", overrides = [
  "project/test_project1/env/source=src"
 ])
 print(cfg)
```

You are providing the conf config directory as your config path. This means all the sub directories are considered config groups.

I suggest you go back and read the Hydra [basic tutorial](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/your_first_app/simple_cli/).
If you want to get deeper, I recommend [The Defaults List](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list/).